# Is there a way to call pandas `get_group` with a key that contains `nan`?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a `DataFrameGroupBy` object that I created with the `groupby` parameter `dropna=False`. The docs state:

> dropna bool, default True
>
> If True, and if group keys contain NA values, NA values together with row/column will  be dropped. If False, NA values will also be treated as the key in groups.

The `DataFrameGroupBy` is created as expected with nan keys, but I get a `KeyError` when looking up the groups with a `nan` key via `DataFrameGroupBy.get_group(key_with_nan)`. I assume this is due to the fact that `np.nan != np.nan`, but does anyone know of a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

I'd fill the `NaN` values with unique object and then do `.groupby`. Consider this dataframe:

```
  Col1  Col2
0    A     1
1    A     2
2    B     3
3    B     4
4    C     5
5  NaN     6
```

Then:

```py
obj = object()  # <-- this object will be instead NaN values

df["Col1"] = df["Col1"].fillna(obj)

g = df.groupby("Col1")
print(g.get_group(obj))
```

Prints:

```
                                Col1  Col2
5  <object object at 0x7f33ba887c00>     6
```